# What does set -xe do in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I've seen bash shell scripts which have this before other commands.

I am aware of what `set -x` does; however, when I tried `-xe`, nothing seemed to change.

does anyone know what does it do? I can't seem to find any documentation on it.

Comment: I wish that before people are quick and hot to press downvote, take a moment and think that perhaps the OP is new to bash, and perhaps they didn't know that you can combine the flags together ? and it's not like finding this info in the docs is straight forward 
This sort of behaviour only discourages new comers from both asking and contributing.

Comment: Read `man bash` . `-xe` is interpreted as `-x -e`.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is at [4.3.1 The Set Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin)

-e is:

> Exit immediately if a pipeline (see Pipelines), which may consist of a
> single simple command (see Simple Commands), a list (see Lists), or a
> compound command (see Compound Commands) returns a non-zero status.
> The shell does not exit if the command that fails is part of the
> command list immediately following a while or until keyword, part of
> the test in an if statement, part of any command executed in a && or
> || list except the command following the final && or ||, any command
> in a pipeline but the last, or if the command’s return status is being
> inverted with !. If a compound command other than a subshell returns a
> non-zero status because a command failed while -e was being ignored,
> the shell does not exit. A trap on ERR, if set, is executed before the
> shell exits.
>
> This option applies to the shell environment and each subshell
> environment separately (see Command Execution Environment), and may
> cause subshells to exit before executing all the commands in the
> subshell.
>
> If a compound command or shell function executes in a context where -e
> is being ignored, none of the commands executed within the compound
> command or function body will be affected by the -e setting, even if
> -e is set and a command returns a failure status. If a compound command or shell function sets -e while executing in a context where
> -e is ignored, that setting will not have any effect until the compound command or the command containing the function call
> completes.